# Detach, sort and reattach at the original position

Tags: jquery, sorting, append, clone, detach

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div id="01" class="visible" data-owner="b"></div>
<div id="02" class="notvisible" data-owner="c"></div>
<div id="03" class="visible" data-owner="x"></div>
<div id="06" class="notvisible" data-owner="a"></div>
<div id="08" class="notvisible" data-owner="b"></div>
```

I want to group and filter the visible different rows into owner groups:

```html
<div class="group" data-user-group="x">
  <div id="03" class="visible" data-owner="x"></div>
</div>
<div class="group" data-user-group="b">
  <div id="01" class="visible" data-owner="b"></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery Code for this works great:

```js
function groupTheVisible() {
  $('div.group').each(function() {
    dataAnchor = $(this).attr('data-user-group');
    $('div.visible[data-owner="' + dataAnchor + '"]').detach().prependTo($(this));
  }  
}

function regroupTheVisible() {
  // ?
}
```

How can I group the visible rows back on the correct position in the original list? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the original elements ordered by their numerical `id`? Also, your JS implies that the `.group` elements exist before you do the sorting. If so, could you please provide a full HTML example with all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier if your first list is located within a container, because in the extreme case that list could get empty and then the script needs to know where to create it again.

So, I will assume a container `div` with `id` "basket".

The snippet below also has some text in the `div` elements, so that the output shows what is happening.

```js
function groupTheVisible() {
    $("div.group").each(function() {
        var dataAnchor = $(this).attr("data-user-group");
        $('div.visible[data-owner="' + dataAnchor + '"]').prependTo(this);
    });
}

function regroupTheVisible() {
    $("div.group > div").each(function() {
        var dataId = $(this).attr("id");
        var $before = $("#basket > div").filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr("id") < dataId;
        });
        if ($before.length) {
            $before.last().after(this);
        } else {
            $("#basket").prepend(this);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket">
    <div id="01" class="visible" data-owner="b">01-B-Visible</div>
    <div id="02" class="notvisible" data-owner="c">02-C-NotVisible</div>
    <div id="03" class="visible" data-owner="x">03-X-Visible</div>
    <div id="06" class="notvisible" data-owner="a">06-A-NotVisible</div>
    <div id="08" class="notvisible" data-owner="b">08-B-NotVisible</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="group" data-user-group="x"></div>
<div class="group" data-user-group="b"></div>

<button onclick="groupTheVisible()">Group the Visible</button>
<button onclick="regroupTheVisible()">Regroup the Visible</button>
```

NB: Make sure to declare your variables with `var` (or `let`, `const`) to avoid that they become global variables.

NB2: As you *move* elements, it is not really necessary to call `detach` on them.